# How to check if all the paths on every line of a file is a valid path in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file with different paths on every line

```
path_1
path_2
...
```

and so on.

I need to check if all these paths are valid ones.

The way I am doing now is to create a new directory (tmp) and then writing

```
while read line; do cp $line > tmp; done < my_paths_file
```

and then checking if the number of files copied into tmp directory is equal to the number of lines in the file. This takes too long due to a lot of number of lines in my file.

Is there a smarter and quicker way to check the validity of all the paths?

Comment: 'path' as in to a directory or to a file?

Comment: @dawg to a file

Comment: You can do `[[ -e path_to_file ]]` to test if a file exists in Bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read `man test` for an explanation of

```
while read -r line; do
  test -d "$line" || echo "$line is not valid"
done < my_paths_file
```

I used `-d` for a directory, alternatives are `-f` for regular files or `-e` for files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
touch valid.file 
while read line; do ls $line >> valid.file; done < my_paths_file
```

All valid filenames will be stored in `valid.file`.

Comment: Use `ls "$line"` avoiding problems with directories like /tmp/stupid dir with spaces`.